# a.zi is not a function on heroku but app works fine on local

Tags: heroku, clojurescript

I have a clojurescript app deployed on Heroku that gives an error when a certain event is triggered. The event triggers fine and the effects occur on the local machine, but not online.

Here's the error that I'm getting in the console:

```
[Error] TypeError: a.zi is not a function. (In 'a.zi(xr.b(b))', 'a.zi' is undefined)
    (anonymous function) (app.js:1143:299)
    MG (app.js:1145:298)
    NG (app.js:1147:192)
    LG (app.js:1142:524)
    (anonymous function) (app.js:1144:242)
    MG (app.js:1145:298)
    b (app.js:1142:570)
    (anonymous function) (app.js:1065:272)
```

What am I to make sense of this and where to even start debugging it?

Comment: Please edit the question to include more details: is your runtime the browser or NodeJS? If using Node, do your version of Node in Heroku and the one in your local machine match? Does your CLJS compilation happen in Heroku or you compile locally?

Comment: runtime is browser and compilation happens on heroku

Comment: Could it be that you are missing an externs file when you are deploying to Heroku? It could be that the name of some function has been changed during advanced compilation, but it shouldn't and that's what extern files are for.

Comment: I don't know how to find out which extern files are missing, do you?

Comment: I also added :compiler-options {:infer-externs :auto} in the build, but that didn't work

Comment: The code is minified during advanced compilation and the minification process probably also minified a function name that should not have been minified. As Denis says you might be missing an externs file (externs prevent certain names from being minified). Does the code work locally if you open the index.html after advanced compilation? Do you have an externs file? If you use [shadow-cljs](https://github.com/thheller/shadow-cljs) as a build tool you can use `shadow-cljs release app --pseudo-names` to help you find missing externs.

Answer (score 1):

These two-letter function names are what you get after the Google Closure Compiler (GCC) has done its advanced optimizations.

Normally when this happens to me, it's because I'm referring into a Javascript library. Let's say library A publishes function `foo` ... let's assume it's published out in the browser as (effectively) `window.A = { foo: function () {}; };`.

Depending on how you've `(:required ,,,)`, GCC can get confused and think that anywhere it sees `foo` it's allowed to rename it. It isn't. There's a few ways to tell it not to. But first, debugging:

Usually the first thing I'd do is re-deploy with `:simple` optimizations instead of `:advanced`. Your bundle size will be bigger, but nothing will have been renamed and so you can at least find the culprit in the devtools. Where you change these settings is going to vary depending on whether you're using lein-figwheel, figwheel.main, ShadowCLJS or clojurescript.main to compile your cljs:

https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#optimizations

Another trick is to turn on pseudo-names and pretty-print and re-deploy.

https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#pseudo-names
https://clojurescript.org/reference/compiler-options#pretty-print

Once you find it, you might want to surround the problem code with `(set! *warn-on-infer* true)`. This gives you some hints where you might want to provide your own compiler hints; these will also opt the  (eg. `(defn a-fn [^js/L.LatLng pos] (.toString pos))` would opt `.toString` out of GCC's renaming if you were working with leaflet).

https://clojurescript.org/guides/externs#externs-inference

Finally, this article has a bunch more tips: https://dev.solita.fi/2020/06/25/taming-cljs-advanced-compilation.html